# geopy: 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.' using 'geodesic.distance' class

Tags: python, geopy, geographic-lib

I'm defining the following function to help calculate the midpoint of three or more points on Earth using the Vincenty formulae. The refs variable is defined globally and I've imported the `pandas`, `geodesic` from `geopy.distance` and `geographiclib` libraries:

```
def midpoint_vincenty(df):
    global refs
    global outputData
    inputDict = {}
    
    for col in df.columns:
        inputList = []
        
        for i, value in df[col].items():
            if pd.notna(value):
                inputLoc = df.at[i, col]
                inputLat = refs.at[inputLoc, 'lat']
                inputLong = refs.at[inputLoc, 'long']
                inputCoord = (inputLat, inputLong)
                inputList.append(inputCoord)
        
        inputDict[col] = inputList
    
    for i in inputDict:
        pointsList = inputDict[i]
        initDistance = geodesic(pointsList[0], pointsList[1]).km
        initBearing = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(pointsList[0][0], pointsList[0][1], pointsList[1][0], pointsList[1][1])['azi1']
        midpoint = geodesic(pointsList[0],pointsList[1]).destination(pointsList[0],initBearing, initDistance/2)
        
        for point in pointsList[2:]:
            iterDistance = geodesic(midpoint, point).km
            iterBearing = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(midpoint[0],midpoint[1],point[0], point[1])['azi1']
            midpoint = geodesic(midpoint, point).destination(midpoint, iterBearing, distance = iterDistance/2)
        inputDict[i] = midpoint
    
    outputData = pd.DataFrame(inputDict)
    outputData = outputData.T[[0,1]]
    return outputData
```

However, when I attempt to pass a data frame containing location names with a given latitude and longitude as the `df` argument, it throws the following error message:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The traceback shows the problem to be coming from the line where `iterDistance` is defined, within the nested for loop at the bottom. This is weird though because the `initDistance` line works absolutely fine using the exact same syntax. `midpoint` is a geopy.point.Point object and `point` is a tuple so I'm not sure it's either of those that are causing the issue as it says that the data type of the object causing the issue is a Series.

I've tried the following:

- Parsing the `point` value as a geopy.point.Point object
- Calculating iterDistance using the `geographiclib` library method that I used for `iterBearing`. This returns 'TypeError: cannot convert the series to class float'
- Passing a smaller test data frame with fewer locations. This returned `outputData` with 0 errors, but I don't know which specific column in my initial `df` input is causing the issues as adding `print (midpoint)` after it's defined for the first time returns the first 33% of my values and I can't see anything wrong in the column after that (column no. 85 out of 237)

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.